# How do I compute the principal values of these complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I compute the principal value of a these complex numbers?

I have 2 examples I'm not sure how to calculate

One being

$$\frac{1}{(1+i)^i}$$

the other is

$$(-1+i\sqrt{3})^{1+i}$$

Can anyone help please? Anything appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{1 \over \pars{1 + \ic}^{\,\ic}} & =
\exp\pars{-\ic\ln\pars{1 + \ic}} =
\exp\pars{-\ic\bracks{\ln\pars{\root{1^{2} + 1^{2}}} +
\arctan\pars{1 \over 1}\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
\exp\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}\,\ic}\exp\pars{\pi \over 4}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px groove navy]{\exp\pars{\pi \over 4}\bracks{\cos\pars{\ln\pars{2} \over 2} -
\ic\,\sin\pars{\ln\pars{2} \over 2}}} \\ &
\end{align}
etc$\ds{\ldots}$

Answer (score 0):

For $z\ne0$, you can use the formula for the principal branch of the logarithm $$\log z=\begin{cases}\ln\lvert z\rvert+i\arccos\frac{\Re z}{\lvert z\rvert}&\text{if }\Im z\ge 0\\ \ln\lvert z\rvert-i\arccos\frac{\Re z}{\lvert z\rvert}&\text{if }\Im z<0\end{cases}$$

And you can apply it in $a^b=e^{b\log a}$.